# Are Fiber Media Converters Technically Modems?

Tags: converter, modem

[Fiber media converters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_media_converter) are devices used to convert fiber optic signals to other types of (digital) network data.

I'm curious as to whether these devices technically fit the definition of a [Modem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modem)? If not, why?

Comment: Do they MOdulate and DEModulate?

Comment: What Transistor said. So, that's up to your definition what already constitutes modulation, and of course the other types of medium. No general answer can be given.

Comment: You might be interested in https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/64456/is-an-ont-a-modem

Comment: do you consider FM radio and/or AM radio to be a modem?

Comment: @old_timer, Depends on what you mean by radio. I'd factor in whether the data was digital or analog, whether it was one-way or two way communication, and whether you are referring to the communication system or the larger device.

Comment: Was for the OP, but I was talking about over the air good old fashioned analog radio stations.

Comment: @old_timer thanks. Personally I never thought of AM/FM radios as modems. They don't usually convert to digital and that's a part of the criteria, no? At any rate, I asked because I'd like to learn what the consensus is in EE in regards to using the term 'modem'.

Comment: this is not a forum for opinion based questions.  and the modulation is analog be it the well used form of a modem or radio stations over the air.  what it carries is a separate layer.

Comment: trying to gauge what you think a modulator demodulator is

Comment: countless things use modulation over a media yes, but the term modem has a specific commonly used place.  for fiber ethernet media you have a phy and optical transceivers

Comment: folks have been using radios to send digital back and forth for a long time now, not radio stations necessarily, some gprs and frs radios made that even easier.  do those not modulate the signal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

Modulation (and demodulation) imply that the information is being imposed on a carrier of some sort, such as the audio tones used in voiceband telephone modems, or the RF carriers used in cable TV and wireless systems.

Ethernet (except for its wireless variations) uses [baseband signaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseband#Digital_baseband_transmission), in which the information symbols are transmitted directly over the wire or optical link.

While it's true that you could think of the light beam itself as a kind of "RF carrier" (on the order of 10<sup>14</sup> to 10<sup>15</sup> Hz), the term "modem" is not generally applied here.

Comment: So, a coherent optical transceiver module would qualify as a modem, then?

Comment: Doesn't "RF" stand for "radio frequency"? I don't think this counts as radio frequency.

Comment: @JohnDvorak hence Dave's "kind of" and the quotation marks, and the parentheses explicitly explaining that.

Comment: But @alex.forencich has a point; personally, I'd consider coherent transceivers as a modem. But, what you plug in into a device that is a "media converter" will typically be a cheap IM-DD intensity detector pluggable transceiver, and that's hardly a modem, but a line receiver. But, ok, the the name IM actually contains "intensity *modulation*"... it's up to interpretation at that point. Anyway, the cheap IM-DD receiver pluggable doesn't contain any of the complicated things "proper" modems usually have to do to get the data out of the analog signal; that's the point here, I think.

Comment: As a historical note, 10BROAD36 described Ethernet over 75 Ohm cable broadband.

Answer (score 8):

All modems are PHYs (physical layers) in the OSI network model, but only some PHYs are complex enough to be considered modems. Why? I think it depends on four things:

- simple or complex modulation
- carrier or baseband
- WAN or local
- historical use

For example, an Ethernet PHY uses simple encoding depending on the speed in use (MLT, PAM). These schemes have a fairly small number of symbols / constellation points, and they're baseband encoded. So is Ethernet a modem? No, at least for 10/100/1000-base types.

Yet as they find more creative ways to squeeze bits out of copper and other media to push Ethernet ever faster, the complexity line between Ethernet 'phy' and 'modem' becomes increasingly blurred. Nevertheless, since Ethernet is a LAN connection only, it's not a modem in that sense. So, not a modem.

A cable modem on the other hand uses QAM modulation which has a large constellation: 64, 256, 1024 or more points. It's a WAN connection too, part of a service network, so it resembles a historical modem in that regard. And it uses carrier frequencies. So it clearly ticks all three boxes: complex, WAN, and uses carrier. So, modem from day one.

How about MoCA? It very definitely uses carrier frequencies with an OFDM-based modulation scheme, but nevertheless isn't considered a modem at least in general usage (generally the term 'adapter' is used for MoCA.) Why? It's LAN only.

Finally, the optical example you show - a media converter - seems to be only changing the electrical to optical and vice-versa, and only in a local point-to-point connection. It’s not doing any significant re-encoding to / from complex modulation scheme, and it's not connecting to a WAN. So, not a modem.

Comment: OFDM with (IIRC) 64 subcarriers has been proposed as an encoding scheme for future Ethernet systems. If those become reality, would you consider the encoding device a mdoem?

Comment: I would argue no since it's LAN, not WAN. See my revised answer.

Comment: What would you say about coherent optical transceiver modules that use QAM, OFDM, etc.?

Comment: Yes, this muddies the water a bit. Is it a carrier grade connection? Then, arguably, it’s a modem using that criterion. If it’s LAN, then no, same reasoning as MoCA based on historical use.